# How to upload image to firebase storage and save reference in the database in single transaction?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I would like to upload image to firebase storage and save link to it in the firebase database. Saving link to database can fail for whatever reason and then I have unused, unlinked image in the storage. Is it possible to somehow ensure that after upload link to the image is saved in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another approach other than using transaction. You can use Firebase Cloud Functions Storage Trigger. You can write a cloud function to get the download URL of the uploaded image and then push it to firebase database.

[Check this video by firebase about Cloud Function Storage Trigger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDLpEn3PbmE&t=25s)

Comment: This is the best solution so far, I wonder though if trigger itself can fail for whatever reason, but probability of that is way much lower than user closing browser for example.

Comment: I have been using cloud function with my Android app. I have never had an ocassion when the trigger had failed till now.

Comment: *** This video has been DEPRECATED as of April 2, 2018 ***  Please visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events .. for the latest info.

Answer (score 3):

How about this pattern.

1. Save the file in cloud storage in a bucket that has a lifecycle of 1 day. We can call it a temporal bucket.
2. Save the url into your database.
3. Have in place a cloud function that will move the object from the temporal bucket to a permanent one. The function can replace the url from the database once the object is in the permanent bucket.

So, in the case you cannot save the url to the database, that object will get deleted after 1 day

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `addOnSuccessListener` on your task like this:

```
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
        firebaseRef.child("urls").child("urlId1").setValue(downloadUrl.toString);
    }
});
```

This means that only if the upload succeeded, you are writting the url to the database.

Comment: My problem is different. It is 'upload image only together with update to database'. So either both successful or both fail.

Comment: So that's why you need to do 2 separate operation. Isn't this what you were asking for? If the upload fails, then nothing is written to the database, if the upload succeeded, only then the urls is written to the database. If can also use `addOnCompleteListener()` when you are writting data.

Comment: Upload can succeed and then url is not written in the database for whatever reason(say user closed browser) and you have image in storage which is not referenced anywhere.

Comment: @AlexMamo But it may upload images successfully, But failed to update data in Firestore so it's better to do something like Transactions and batched writes in Firestore but works with storage

Comment: @AlexMamo I hope I can see any update for solving this problem in Firebase Summit 2021

Comment: @muco2 This answer explains how to write the download URL to the Realtime Database. However, you can also do it in Firestore. There is no need for any transaction or batch writes when it comes to a single `set()` operation. Besides that, don't forget to attach a listener to the write operation to always see if something goes wrong.

Comment: @AlexMamo Let's suppose the user uploads a new post and this post has an image and after upload the image, The connection is lost, So I can't create the post in Firestore and that image will be not related to anything.

I can solve the problem when get calling from failure listener but it's not a good idea because the user maybe leave the app or thousands of scenario like this that make a connection not complete so it's a good idea to do something like [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) but works with Firestore and Storage

Comment: @muco2 Inevitably, that can happen. For more info, check my answer from the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58999036/firebase-firestore-and-cloud-storage-deleting-both-a-db-entry-and-its-associate). However, a transaction doesn't solve that problem, and can only be used when writing data to Firestore.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you wait for the image to get uploaded in the firebase, get the URL from the storageRef and then push the Url into the database like below.
I'm using javascript method, I hope you will get an idea on how to achieve your need.

```
<input type="file" value="" name="Photo" class="btn btn-info" id="fileButton" accept="image/*"> //html Code
```

In js file, add event listener like

```
var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');
fileButton.addEventListener("change",function(e){
   var file= e.target.files[0];
   //create storage ref to the firebase storage
   var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('your Path Name').child(file.name);
   var task = storageRef.put(file);
   task.on("state_changed",function(snapshot){
      var percentage= snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes) *100;
      if(percentage==100){
          storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
             // You will get the Url here.
            var firebaseRef=firebase.database().ref("Your path Name);
            firebaseRef.push(url).then(function(){
              alert("Image Uploaded and also updated to the database");
           });
          });
      }
   });
});
```

I hope this helps you, this happens in a single transaction.

Comment: This is not a single transaction. If the database push fails, the file is still uploaded.