# Firebase Firestore and Cloud Storage: deleting both a DB entry and its associated file can result in one being actually deleted, the other not

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to be sure that if my Android app's user wants to delete a Firestore DB document AND the associated file stored in Cloud Storage (identified by the DB document's ID), then actually both of them will be deleted?

Indeed, we can imagine that in the situation of a promise related to the DB document's deletion, the file's deletion could fail: in this context, the DB entry would have really been deleted but not the associated file. Resulting in an inconsistent state for the Android project...

How could I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to be sure that if my Android app's user wants to delete a Firestore DB document AND the associated file stored in Cloud Storage (identified by the DB document's ID), then actually both of them will be deleted?

If you think that you can add to a batch operation a Firestore delete operation and a Firebase Storage delete operation and be sure that both happen in the same, please note that this is not possible. These operations are apart of different Firebase services and there is no way you can make them atomic.

Unfortunately, none of the Firebase products support cross-product transactional operations. To solve this, you'll have to nest the calls during your delete operations, meaning that if you get an error that occurs when you delete a record from FireStore, then you have to delete the corresponding image from Firebase Storage. But at some point in time, there will be a failure that the client can't rollback. The most common approach for these inevitable failures that might happen, is to make your code robust by handling exceptions and perform occasional cleanups in both places, Firestore, and Firebase Storage.

Comment: Thank you. " meaning that if you **DON'T** get an error occurs when you delete a record from FireStore, then you can delete the corresponding image from Firebase Storage." : did you forget the **"DON'T"**? - "by handling exceptions and perform occasional cleanups in both places, Firestore and Firebase Storage.": I think the client (Android smartphone of the user) shouldn't do that, so I should put the deletion code into Google servers (for example using Cloud Functions), no?

Comment: No, if for example, you get an error when you try to write the url of a picture in Firestore, so the operation failed, then you should rollback the operation by deleting the image from Firestore. In this case, you can have consistent data. Is it ok now?