# Manually Storing images in Firebase Storage from browser .How to make it reflect in real time database. so that I can fetch in Android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

[image]

I have uploaded the images using upload button from storage tab of project and trying to fetch them into app, But the app is not fetching the images because the changes are not reflected in the real time database of the same project.
[image: Realtime database picturev]

AS you can see the changes are not reflected in the database. Is their any way to do it?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be reflected in the real-time database? They both are separate services.

Comment: can you point me tutorial which show application of "only" firebase storage to retrieve image because all i found was using both  and in when user upload from mobile using coding it is reflected in both,

Comment: Check Doug's answer. Firebase Storage & Real-time database are not linked. You can even use your own database to achieve your requirement. In the tutorials you are referring to, the linking is done programmatically in code.

Answer (score 0):

Files uploaded to Cloud Storage do not automatically get added to Realtime Database.  You will have to write code to associate any files in storage to records in a database.

You could use a [Storage trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) to do this automatically if you want.  You will have to determine for yourself what data to write in the database when a file is uploaded.

Comment: I am uploading the images manually via browser so how would be this function triggered .Do I have to monitor it(the storage bucked) continuously for changes? how would i do that

Comment: Or do i really need to use real time database can i not only use firebase store for fetching images avoiding all this?

Comment: The function will trigger no matter how a file is uploaded.  Try it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading images to storage will not reflect any changes in realtime database.
You can load images from storage to your app using Glide or Picasso.But you may need URLs of those images.
If you can store image URLs to realtime database,then it is easy.

For that you can use Storage Trigger as mentioned by @Doug Stevenson

Check out the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012372/how-to-upload-image-to-firebase-storage-and-save-reference-in-the-database-in-si#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20Firebase%20Cloud,push%20it%20to%20firebase%20database.&text=How%20about%20this%20pattern.&text=The%20function%20can%20replace%20the,is%20in%20the%20permanent%20bucket.) question.

Comment: it there not any way to get images directly form storage without using firebase database?